# clang hangs when compiling libCVD on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, clang

[libCVD](http://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/) is a fairly standard library but when I try to build it using clang (the version that ships with XCode 5) it hangs on the target cvd_src/fast/fast_7_score.o

Has anybody else had experience with clang hanging on compilation or has been able to successfully build this library?

Comment: Hangs? Have you tried sampling it? Changing the optimization level? Trying earlier versions of Clang (or GCC) bundled with Xcode or compiling LLVM/Clang from source?

Comment: Also, hanging is not a terribly common compiler failure (IME, crashing, miscompilation and resource exhaustion are more likely).  Is Clang using 100% CPU for many minutes, or trying to allocate gigabytes of memory?  Take a look at top and/or Activity Monitor while Xcode is compiling. Finally, it's possible that Clang is just very slow on this file — how long have you waited?

Comment: I've waited over an hour and it hangs on one file in particular. It doesn't seem to be using all my memory. I've also tried this with the most recent version of Clang and have the same issue (compiles fine with GCC)

Comment: Well, in that case, try to see if it's related to the optimization level.  What did the sample look like?  If it indeed happens with current SVN Clang, then file a bug on llvm.org/bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Compilation began hanging for me after upgrading to Mavericks.

Activity Monitor reported a high CPU usage for `xcrun`.  My googling took me to this question, as well as to [Xcode 4 Mavericks Creating Universal Binary for OSX hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814946/xcode-4-mavericks-creating-universal-binary-for-osx-hangs).  I followed the advice given by [user2965639](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2965639/user2965639) in the accepted answer for that question and I was able to compile again without any issue, so I thought perhaps this would be useful to share here as well.  Here are the commands I ran:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/lipo /usr/bin/lipo.orig
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo /usr/bin/lipo
```

Comment: This problem isn't only affecting libCVD FYI :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove line `OFLAGS=-O3` altogether in the Makefile generated by running `./configure_osx_32bit`. That will get you past hang.

Comment: Thanks. After trying different optimisation levels, I find `OFLAGS=-O1` is OK, but `-O2` or above hangs the compiler.