# Xcode 4 Mavericks Creating Universal Binary for OSX hangs

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, universal-binary

was it ever possbile to create a C++ command line tool as a fat binary in XCode (32bit and 64bit in one file)? I thought it was, but if I try it now, XCode hangs during "Creating Universal Binary."

I updated to OSX Mavericks and I am using XCode 4.6.2. It doesn't matter which compiler I choose. As soon as I set "Build Active Architecture Only" to false, the compiler hangs during "Creating Universal Binary". 
Additionally I am building a static C++ library in my project which has no problems to be build for 32 and 64 bit in one file.

I hope you can help me.

Cheers
Georg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating to Mavericks. Both Xcode 4.6.3. and Xcode 3.2.6 were hanginig endlessly during "Creating Universal Binary."

As it's the `lipo` command line tool that's creating the universal binaries I did some research and found this discussion which solved my problems:
[Installing psycopg2 has it stuck between xcrun and lipo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667916/installing-psycopg2-has-it-stuck-between-xcrun-and-lipo)

According to the answers given there Xcode apparently didn't find `lipo` in the end but unfortunately shows no error message in this case.

After backing up the 10.9 version of `/usr/bin/lipo` and linking in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo` as described in the post creating the universal binaries was working again.

Comment: Unbelievable. Solved my problem too. But this is truly worrisome because with multiple Xcode installed, linking in particular tool in the chain may cause disaster later. I thought Xcode-select can handle this but apparently it is buggy on Mavericks.

Comment: An alternative solution is to upgrade to XCode 5.x